# Base32 character conversion to a 5bit value, Python to Java

Tags: python, java, converters

I have some Python code where each given Base32 character is converted to a 5bit value.

I need to rewrite it in Java, but I don't know the Java equivalent/syntax for this format function.

```
word_safe_alphabet = "23456789CFGHJMPQRVWXcfghjmpqrvwx"
    d = {}
    i=0
    for char in word_safe_alphabet:
        # Create 5 bit patterns for each character in the alphabet
        # Start with bit pattern for index 0, to index 31: 00000 -> 11111
        d[char] = "{0:05b}".format(i)
        i+=1
```

5 bit, because we have 32 possible characters in the alphabet, thus the highest index is 31, which needs 5 bits to be represented => 11111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
class Binary {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String word_safe_alphabet = "23456789CFGHJMPQRVWXcfghjmpqrvwx";
        for(int i=0; i<word_safe_alphabet.length(); i++){
            int charNr = Character.getNumericValue(word_safe_alphabet.charAt(i))-2;
            String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(charNr);
            System.out.println(String.format("%5s", binary).replaceAll(" ", "0"));
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see this is how it should be, thank you a great deal.